# Could we queue up edit reviews so that hasty reviews don't take precedence?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-queues, suggested-edits

A comment on another question led me to believe that apparently the first few reviews to an edit to be submitted are the ones which determine the actual outcome of the review. This seems to be the opposite of what we want- we want the careful, thought out reviews not to always be outraced by the robo-reviews, right? (If this isn't actually how it works, let me know, because that would probably render the rest of this question pointless!)

A way to mitigate this which would be relatively lightweight and more or less invisible to the user would be to evaluate the reviews in the order in which they're started, rather than finished. The process might be something like:

- When somebody first loads the review page, the timestamp of the page load is recorded as the start of the review
- The reviews are ordered in a queue by their starting timestamp
- If the review at the front of this queue is completed, then that review is used for the edit, and removed from the queue
- If the review at the front of the queue is not completed and takes more than a certain length of time (say, 30s, but it could be whatever), then the starting time is reset to the current time, moving that review to the back of the queue
- If a review not at the front of the queue is completed, that review isn't actually used until it reaches the front of the queue
- When enough reviews have been fully completed and accepted from the front of the queue as described above, the outcome is applied to the edit, and all other reviews in the queue, no matter their status, are discarded.

This wouldn't prevent robo-reviewers, but it would help mitigate their effect by preventing quick, careless reviews from being so overwhelmingly likely to beat more careful reviews. It would also hopefully mean rep-farming edits would be less likely to be accepted and so potentially reduce the volume being attempted once people realised this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is... Really complicated. And review ain't exactly a *simple* system to start with.

We're going [a different route](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260341/dont-allow-suggested-edits-to-be-finished-while-someone-has-clicked-improve/270498#270498) in our efforts to address this problem:

> As of [late last week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039), we're now giving suggested-edit reviewers a limited period of exclusivity.

I think this will serve to accomplish the same goals with *relative* simplicity.

Comment: I don't know how frequent the case of several people being given the same suggestion before any of them view it is. If it's not TOO frequent then yes, that seems just as good and obviously simpler.