# Don't allow suggested edits to be "finished" while someone has clicked "improve"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, suggested-edits

If someone has clicked "improve" in the suggested edits queue, it should **not be possible** for the suggested edit to be approved **until the person who's clicked improve has finished**.

[Inspiration for this suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260268/edit-hunting-and-possible-reputation-farming-how-should-i-react/260276#260276)

[image: Relevant passage from other meta post]

This has happened to me and other users before: We read an edit, decide it needs improvement... and by the time we go through all the work, the original edit has been approved by less thorough people.

#### Let's reward people who click improve: lock up that third "approve" slot until they've finished improving

Some ideas about details from the comments:

1. Have a timeout, e.g. 10 minutes, to unlock the edit for approval / rejection
2. Maybe only allow a user to "lock" one suggested edit at a time. If they request another edit to improve, the first edit is automatically unlocked.
3. This idea could cause a backlog if too many people leave edits in "improve" for too long.

   - However, this shouldn't be a concern with a timeout.
   - Perhaps don't display the edit as being in the queue at all if it's pending an "improved" edit.

Comment: I could really get behind this; on the other hand, my sole goal in the Suggested Edit queue would be to click the "Improve" button as quickly as possible to lock up an edit, which may cause a backlog if enough people do the same thing, but I think it's worth the risk.  This would actually bring me back to the Suggested Edit queue.  It *could* also be used as a malicious way to ensure that a user temporarily gets a Suggested Edit ban by ensuring that you can uncheck the "This edit was helpful" flag on a specific user repeatedly.  Then again, I kind of like that idea.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables that's one reason I suggested the timeout. Or perhaps have the timeout somehow based on activity on the page, e.g. more than 1 minute goes by without a change to the edit box

Comment: Shouldn't the 'improved' edit simply override the approved edit in this case?

Comment: @Joe: what if in the mean time someone else suggested an edit?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I don't see that as happening frequently.  Having Suggested Edits approved quickly I buy, having a second edit suggested immediately after an approved edit AND in the short amount of time it should take you to fix a title/etc. in most instances I don't buy as common.  I doubt it happens frequently enough to be concerned about.

Comment: @Joe That doesn't address the problem of people offering really minor edits to posts getting approved and +2 rep (the idea being the improver would uncheck "this post was helpful")

Comment: @durron597 That's because I don't care in the slightest about that.  If you want to get rep 2 at a time up to 2000, have at it.  It's not like you get a free car when you hit 2000.  Imaginary internet points are imaginary, and not worth my trouble to worry about.  You don't need to contort yourself or introduce potential exploits in a system to deal with trivialities of immature people gaming a system in an irrelevant fashion.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260331/could-we-queue-up-edit-reviews-so-that-hasty-reviews-dont-take-precedence

Comment: @Joe - for me, the concern was never the points; it was the continued crappy edits and the rapid-fire approval of them all.  Heck, if someone is making lots of improvements, let them have their two points.

Comment: Maybe even more than 10 minutes timeout, but **1 user can only lock one review at a time**. By the time they request/lock the next review, the first one gets unlocked.

Comment: I think I've seen similar discussions here before, but I definitely believe that this is a real problem looking for a solution. For me the problem is less with making minor tweaks to the edits, but more with cases where I think more substantial improvements are needed. Since doing that will take me a couple of minutes, most of the time somebody else will have made a more minor edit, and I can't save my much more thorough edit. As a result, I pretty much stopped making significant improvements to entries in the edit review queue.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As of [late last week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039), we're now giving suggested-edit reviewers a limited period of exclusivity. What this means:

- When you view a pending suggested edit, the system will avoid assigning that edit to any other reviewers until you've submitted your review or a reasonable period of time (currently 3 minutes) has passed. The number of "in review" tasks is tracked, and the main /review page updates the counts accordingly.
- We don't actually *block* multiple reviewers, so if you open the suggested edit from the question page (rather than being assigned it by the system via /review) or happen to have a link directly to it somehow, you'll be given the opportunity to review it regardless of who else currently has it open.
- If you don't explicitly take action on a review (approve / reject / improve / skip), it won't be assigned to anyone else (or appear in the counts shown under /review) until your period of exclusivity expires.

Three minutes might not seem that long - but due to how the system operates, it can actually be slightly longer before these are actually handed out to anyone else... And even then, this is only a problem if the next reviewer(s) manage to *complete* the review before you're done editing - keeping in mind that the task is also locked to each subsequent reviewer until *their* review is completed. I spent a bit of time testing this today, and had no problem completing even fairly extensive edits - given the often time-sensitive nature of editing, I think this is a reasonable compromise that works to satisfy the *spirit* of your request.

Comment: SO or network wide?

Comment: Everywhere. Note that the post I'm linking to is on Meta SE.

Comment: Sounds like a great improvement. 3 minutes might be a little short if you hit Improve, and the post needs fairly substantial editing. Would it potentially make sense to extend the exclusivity timeout when somebody starts editing the post using the Improve button? Putting in the effort to make a substantial edit, and then not being able to save it, is extremely frustrating (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260969/what-makes-an-edit-more-thorough-than-another-and-how-can-i-save-if-mine-is-m).

Comment: @RetoKoradi 3 min allow a workaround for those aiming at long, effort consuming edit: 1) hit improve 2) take 2 min to do (preferably most critical) part of the edit 3) hit Save (_this will drop the post from the queue_) 4) get back to the post off the queue and continue editing