# What makes an edit "more thorough" than another? And how can I save if mine is more thorough?

Tags: support, review-queues

My question is related to this earlier question on Meta Stack Exchange, but I don't really see my direct question answered there:

[Improvements to a suggested edit cannot be submitted when the suggestion is approved during editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145565/improvements-to-a-suggested-edit-cannot-be-submitted-when-the-suggestion-is-appr)

I run into the following situation frequently when working on the edit review queue:

1. I see an edit that makes some improvements, but the post could use a lot more work.
2. I click the "Improve" button, and do a thorough cleanup of the whole post.
3. I click "Submit".
4. The system tells me that somebody else also edited the same post in the meantime, with a message ending in:

> Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit.

It's unclear to me what exactly this is telling me, and how I should react to it:

- Is the message telling me that the system decided that my edit was not more thorough? Or is it asking me to check if my edit is more thorough? It almost has to be the second option, because in most cases the earlier edit was very minor, and mine is much more extensive and thorough.
- If I do decide that my edit is more thorough, after looking at the conflicting edit, how can I save my edit? I have not found a way to do that, even though the message suggests that I can save it in that case.

I know the basic underlying problem has been discussed before. Attempting to improve edits in the edit review queue is mostly a fruitless endeavor with the current system. If I take the time to make a thorough improvement, I can almost never save it. But I would be happy to get clarification on how the current system works, and hope that suggested improvements like this one also get attention:

[Don't allow suggested edits to be "finished" while someone has clicked "improve"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260341/dont-allow-suggested-edits-to-be-finished-while-someone-has-clicked-improve#comment43457_260341)

Comment: [Yes, this is thoroughly broken.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134324/allow-manual-override-for-edits)

Answer (score 8):

It basically means that someone else has edited the post, and their edit is longer than yours, so it's refusing to merge your edit in as it would remove information instead of add it.

Really there's nothing you can do about it. When I have this problem (or the `This post has been edited x times` message), I copy my edit to notepad, go to the post and see if there's any changes I made which the quick-fingered editor missed.

Comment: Yes, what you're suggesting sounds like the only "solution" I found. I was really hoping that there was something better I was missing. In the cases I saw, the other edit was definitely not longer, though. I could have edited 10 times as much, and it seemed to suggest that the other edit was more thorough.

Comment: Well, if the user editing could see the pending edit(s) that would be helpful.