# This post has been edited 2 times since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit

Tags: support, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

From the review queue I often (more than 100 times so far) "accept and edit" or "reject and edit". But today, for the first time, I've seen a strange orange banner. And on top of that, I've seen it twice in a few minutes interval:

> This post has been **edited** 2 times since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit.

[image: banner "This post has been edited 2 times since you began"]
Both times, when I looked at the "[edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43355418/revisions)" posts, I could only see my own edits. **Where are the other "2 times since you began"?**

Even [the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15821238) itself is silent on who are the other two since I began.

What am I supposed to see? Does it mean I need to wait, and maybe in a few minutes there will be someone completing its own more thorough edit that will cancel/delete/replace my revision?

Otherwise, what's the point to show me this banner?

Note that I seem to be in the opposite situation as in [What makes an edit "more thorough" than another? And how can I save if mine is more thorough?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260969/what-makes-an-edit-more-thorough-than-another-and-how-can-i-save-if-mine-is-m)

Comment: Thanks. Now I know it's not just me.

Comment: Since the revision history has no other edits other than the one you accepted and tried to improve upon, this message seems very fishy.  It might even suggest it is a bug, either because the message was in error, or because something else (like a rejected suggested edit, or a late edit accept vote) triggered the message

Comment: You do get a 5 minute grace period on edits which all get merged into the original edit event so that might have happened.

Comment: What, imaginary edits don't count now?

Comment: @NathanOliver I do not understand what is a merge result: would it be a community edit?

Comment: Nathan means that when OP edits his question during the 5 minute grace period after creating the question, then their edit gets merged into the original/intial version of the question. So when you started editing in that period, then you get the mentioned notice, but won't see the edits in the history.

Comment: @Tom then it doesn't apply in the given example, as it was published hours before my edit.

Comment: Oh, didn't noticed that the question is that old. But you're right, the grace period of the question doesn't apply here, because a reverted edit inside the "edit grace period" will be noted in the edit history as "[Removed during grace period]".

Comment: Oh look, another point of data supporting a temporary edit lock... even if it is an edge case. *sips tea*

Comment: Could there have been now **rejected** edits on the post? (I don't think they show up in the post history.) Not sure if someone can submit an edit when there's already a pending one... If so, could that cause this?

Comment: Hm. They do show up on the timeline, though. Here's [the post in question's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43355418/timeline).

Comment: @NathanOliver: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296612/383779 seems to contradict your observation.