# What's the best practice for harmful suggested edits, when you have edit privileges?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-abuse

Sometimes I see a suggested edit that I feel very certain should not be made, because it's harmful or spammy. I know, of course, to Reject it with whatever reason I feel is best, but you can almost guarantee it'll get multiple Approve votes, and that means that often it will be made.

Most edits I wouldn't care enough to spend any more time thinking about, because while I may feel they're poor by site standards, I don't see them as harmful.

For those that do seem "actively bad", is there anything better I should be doing than saving a link to it, checking back periodically, and doing a rollback if it's approved? I have enough rep to apply a rollback or other edit instantly.

It's an odd situation to me, being able to see what I feel is best to do in the future—but it's not then, yet.

Are there best practices for these situations?

Comment: Reject and Edit?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If it's a severe case which non-robo-reviewers should catch, you might save a link *to the review*, reject for an appropriate reason and use it as a honey-pot:
Roll back if needed, and consider informing the mods of any particularly bad reviewers (give as much evidence as you can, please, *after concisely making clear why* you flagged). Check their other reviews and add further examples to establish those bad reviewers have a pattern.

If it's not such a severe case, you don't have the time, patience, or aren't in the mood to hunt robots, consider doing a "reject-and-edit" if you can find some worthwhile edit to do on the post.
You can go back to the review afterwards if you want to find out if anyone approved it and warrants further investigation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I think almost all of them will be useful for me. I don't think I've seen anything so terrible yet that I'd spend much time investigating the other reviewers. If there was a "suggested suggested edit review audit" box I might drop some in there.

Comment: @DanGetz: In particular, to minimize the window of approval vulnerability, see if you can make some small-but-correct edit quickly, then open the original post (using the browser history in some fashion -- right-click on the back button and middle-click on the review entry?) to make a more thorough edit within the edit grace period.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Need not be *that* fast though: There's an at least 3 minute window of exclusivity. Not sure whether it was made longer...

Comment: @Deduplicator: That's actually not always reliable, since it's entirely possible for someone to load the suggestion, the window to expire for them, you load the suggestion and decide it's wrong, and then they go ahead and approve it. Not only is this possible, it has happened to me *repeatedly*.

Comment: "When you have the rep to check their other reviews..." Actually, you need exactly 0 rep to view other people's reviews. Just go to their profile (activity tab) -> all actions -> reviews. Click on the action, not the post.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Sure, that's because it isn't actually locking. Anyway, found the answer where Shog9 speaks about it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270498

Comment: @Scimonster: Well, you are right. I thought it needed a few points. But it turns out that's only for the complete history of the individual review-queues.