# Facilitate suggested edits review for added/removed tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-queues, suggested-edits

When reviewing edits that added or removed tag(s), the first thing I do is read the whole post to search a reference to this tag (sometimes using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but I don't think that I should only consider perfect matches). While many of these edits are (IMO) too minor, some are legitimate, so I try hard to understand why such tag should be removed or added.

Sometimes, this task is so long that this suggested edit got accepted before I completed the review. I personally think that what would help reviewers is highlighting the words matching added/removed tags in the post.

Of course, with such a feature, reviewers would not be supposed to reject all "removed tag" edits only if a matching word is still present, or reject all "added tag" edits only if no matching word is present. But let's imagine these two cases:

- **A tag was added** (e.g. [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)). In the review page, the matching word (i.e. all occurrences of `Python` or `python`) is highlighted in the compare view. The reviewer first focuses on this(these) occurrence(s). If it's enough to accept the edit, (s)he accepts it. If not, falls back to old-school reviewing.
- **A tag was removed** (e.g. [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)). In the review page, the remaining matching word (i.e. all occurrences of `Python` or `python`) is highlighted in the compare view. The reviewer first focuses on this(these) occurrence(s). If it's enough to accept the edit (e.g. minor reference to Python like *"...but it works with Python"*), (s)he accepts it. If not, falls back to old-school reviewing. This case is common since novice users let the automatic tags suggestion system add tags for them.

**EDIT:**

- I'm not complaining *only* on the fact that I don't have enough time to complete the review before another reviewer, but also on the time spent to review the edit (i.e. it would still annoy me even if i am the last and unique SO user on earth! - guess I wouldn't have much to review though...)
- I do not propose to automate such reviews (nor encourage automation), I just propose to facilitate it, like the current compare view does (it highlights some elements, but you have to understand the whole context)

Comment: *"Sometimes, this task is so long that this suggested edit got accepted before I completed the review."* What you describe is just a special case of a more general problem: reviewers who blow through reviews too quickly. See, for example, [Don't allow suggested edits to be “finished” while someone has clicked “improve”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260341/dont-allow-suggested-edits-to-be-finished-while-someone-has-clicked-improve) and [Could we queue up edit reviews so that hasty reviews don't take precedence?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260331/176646).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I understand your comment and I agree. Yet, such a new feature would also be great even if you're the only reviewer for this suggested edit (less time spent on each review)

Comment: The suggested edit review system was [changed very recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238039). The review is *exclusively yours* [for up to 3 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238898), so take your time to do a proper review!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for these good news! Yet, like I said in my previous comment, such a new feature would also be great even if you're the only reviewer for this suggested edit (less time spent on each review). I've updated my question to reflect this, I guess I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: To downvoters: care to explain why you think that spending less time reviewing such edits is a bad idea? I do not propose to automate such reviews, I just propose to facilitate it, like the current compare view does (it highlights some elements, but you have to understand the whole context).

Answer (score 9):

I don't much care for your technique here, or rather I don't think I like the technique you'd be *encouraging* by focusing reviewers in this manner.

Here's what I do when I review tag edits:

[image: Don't understand the topic? SKIP!]

The important step here is that you **don't review it if you don't know *anything* about the topic and don't care to learn.** Basing your tag approvals / rejections on *keyword frequency* makes you no more use than the tag suggester - if we were going to go that way, we might as well go all-out and just *automatically* reject or approve edits that correspond to tags that the system would've suggested anyway.

Don't make yourself into an automaton. If you're taking the time to review, make it an opportunity to put your knowledge to work - or increase your knowledge!

Comment: I use a filter, so I only see reviews with specific tags.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree, I don't want to make reviewers automatons. This is why I said in my question: _"Of course, with such a feature, reviewers would not be supposed to reject all "removed tag" edits only if a matching word is still present, or reject all "added tag" edits only if no matching word is present"_. I think that what I suggest would be an helpful feature: in your workflow, if you focus on the activity "Are added tags relevant to question?", how do you perform such activity? Would my suggested feature help you in any way to complete this activity? I personally think it would.

Comment: No, it wouldn't @xav - because I'm not scanning for keywords, I'm actually *reading the post*. Now, this may boil down to a difference in style - I personally find it really irritating when folks use those yellow highlighter markers in textbooks too, while clearly some folks find them useful. But if that's your style, just use your browser's search function - don't build that into the system.