# We have a [flappy-bird-clone] tag? Really?

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

[flappy-bird-clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flappy-bird-clone)

I think this tag should be burninated, as I can't see it being useful to anyone, but maybe I'm wrong on this?

Comment: With only 70 questions. That's only about one question for every 1000 Flappy Bird clones on the app store.

Comment: Up-voted because apparently, we **do** have a [flappy-bird-clone] tag, and I share your... confusion. Still; I agree with Shog9, and @BilltheLizard is just trolling you! ;)

Comment: I can't wait to get the gold badge in `flappy-bird-clone` so I can close what must be a multitude of questions in this ubiquitous topic.  Just 1000 more rep to go.

Comment: Perhaps it is not a technical topic. But it seems to be a good learning experience to create a flappy bird clone, and if that tag brings people together to learn, then good for them. If there is a net positive effect, let it be.

Comment: For those that don't know what Flappy Birds are (like me), [here it goes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flappy_Bird)

Comment: I'm tempted to look at the questions tagged with it now

Comment: Huh, yet we don't have a `[minecraft-clone]` tag... Maybe gamedev exchange has one.

Comment: I'm more surprised at the quality of the questions. Only 2 questions downvoted & they are from the same user in a 2 minute timespan

Comment: I'm glad to have such a tag. So I can put it into my **ignored** list.

Comment: Speaking of clones, I think I saw those green pipes in another castle... err, I mean another game.

Comment: Flappy Bird has become sort of like a standard tutorial for making games. So it might become a more useful tag in the future.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Presumably it could be useful to folks writing clones of the "Flappy Bird" game—an activity that, for whatever reason, appears to be somewhat popular.

Now, I *personally* don't believe that folks should be writing Flappy Bird clones. Or CRM systems. But it's not my place to impose those personal preferences on others, who may not even have a say themselves in what they're assigned to implement.

#### See also:

- [Should we burn [sudoku]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273080/should-we-burn-sudoku)
- [Tag merge or burninate candidates: "tic-tac-toe" and "tictactoe"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273083/tag-merge-or-burninate-candidates-tic-tac-toe-and-tictactoe)

Comment: Thanks; I didn't know we had a precedent for this. I think you should add in the direct link to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ also, even though you can get to it through the others.

Comment: Well, you weren't claiming they were meta tags here... You might find this useful though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191

Comment: I didn't know meta-tags existed before this, so I appreciate all the info.

Comment: (Although I do feel sad that you compared Flappy Bird to Sudoku...)

Comment: I see a difference between a Flappy Bird clone, though, and Sudoku/TicTacToe. The latter are games in the most general sense - nobody "owns" or "created" them specifically and they make sense as familiar, common exercises. The former, though, is a specific commercial product that's being knocked-off. How would we feel about, say, "mario-clone"?

Comment: It passes the test of "can someone be an expert in flappy bird clones?"

Comment: @sphanley Someone at some time created those games, and they were most likely "knocked-off" by someone who made them more popular (just look at the history of Sudoku). So just think that in 50 or 100 years from now Flappy Bird could be that generations Sudoku/Tic-Tac-Toe. I imagine interactive newspapers with built-in Flappy Bird clones to pass the time instead of paper puzzles.

Comment: Flappy Bird is a ripoff of countless games that have appeared in the past 25 years or more; it just combined a few factors (a big one being luck) in a way that let it take off.

Comment: "Or CRM systems" ouch

Comment: @sphanley [Tetris (91 questions tagged)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tetris) is owned by [The Tetris Company](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tetris_Company#Legal_enforcement).

Comment: @kmoe Shog's right though. Too many people reinventing that wheel...

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I agree. The "ouch" is because I'm a CRM consultant. ;)

Comment: So...could we replace it with [helicopter-game]? (I have not played Flappy Bird, but my understanding is that it's helicopter-like. (I guess Helicopter isn't really a generic term either, unfortunately...)

Comment: `If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag` <- this. [flappy-bird-clone] tells me nothing about the language, the implementation, etc.

Comment: Neither do [heap] or [quicksort], @qix. Not all programming problems are glorified syntax errors.

Comment: That's a really poor comparison to [flappy-bird-clone]. Where do we draw the line @Shog9?

Comment: Maybe all of those could be merged into [2d-games]?

Comment: [Here's how I decide where to draw that line](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270462/facilitate-suggested-edits-review-for-added-removed-tags/270501#270501), @Qix. The whole point of a folksonomy is that it doesn't require a huge bureaucratic system to facilitate categorization - if we need more than a few simple rules for tags then we shouldn't be using tags at all.

Comment: @Shog9 So what you're saying, is that anything **remotely relevant** to the question is acceptable.

Comment: "Remotely relevant" == acceptable? Not so much, @Qix - rather, relevance should be your test - the more relevant the tag to the problem being solved, the more acceptable it becomes.

Comment: @Shog9 Could you provide an example of where [flappy-bird-clone] would help in solving the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868852/how-to-spawn-ccsprites-in-random-heights-like-flappy-bird