# Tag merge or burninate candidates: "tic-tac-toe" and "tictactoe"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[tic-tac-toe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe) has 102 questions, and it's competitor [tictactoe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tictactoe) a whopping 35.

Shall we merge these (preferably with `tictactoe` added as a synonym to `tic-tac-toe`)?

Or do we take the flamethrower to them; they do seem awfully meta to me. If these are indeed meta tags, we'd need to raze [2d-games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2d-games), [chess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chess) and probably more to the ground too.

Comment: Should they even exist? Sounds like a top-of-the-line Meta tag.

Comment: @animuson: agreed, updated the premise.

Comment: @animuson: in which case [`2d-games`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2d-games) is another one.

Comment: If they have that many questions tagged (assuming they're relevant) then they're probably not Meta.  Wouldn't tictactoe refer to the content, therefore not be Meta.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: but can the problem posed by each question still be answered if it wasn't about tic-tac-toe but something else?

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Example: [Can getMouse act on one specific object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14429909) There is nothing here that is specific to tic-tac-toe. I cleaned up the tags and added one that was actually relevant to this question, namely the graphics library used.

Comment: These questions are more "I'm having *this problem* when building a TicTacToe game." And a lot of them also follow the "I have a TicTacToe assignment for school, can you help me with *this*?"

Comment: If you want to get rid of the games (I would agree) then there's also [tag:chess]...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: There will be more.. `chess` is often about min-max algorithms instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the tags are both used for the same purpose, I would merge them, and eventually make [tictactoe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tictactoe) a synonym of [tic-tac-toe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe), which I find easier to read than [tictactoe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tictactoe).

I would not call the tags meta, as they are used for questions about an implementation of the Tic Tac Toe game in a programming language. It is similar to [conways-game-of-life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conways-game-of-life) used for the Game of Life.
If I am asking a question about how to implement my version of Game of Life, I would tag it [conways-game-of-life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conways-game-of-life), just in the case there are users who can better answer those questions. I would do the same with [tic-tac-toe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe).

Clearly, if there aren't users who can better answer those questions, the tags could be useless.

Comment: Most of the tags in either `tic-tac-toe` or `tictactoe` are not about the game itself, but rather a more specific problem where the OP just happens to be coding a tic-tac-toe game. I'll just have to manually clean those up, and ignore the other game tags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: that means that *those questions* should not have been using the tag, but if I ask about an algorithm to win Tic-Tac-Toe, then  [tag:tic-tac-toe] is entirely appropriate (not that such a question would be particularly intriguing ...).

Comment: @JoachimSauer: yup, and thus there are very few (if any!) such questions using those tags at the moment..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not expecting the tag to be about the game itself. It is like with [tag:drupal-views]: The question could be about the Views module, but it could be also about integration code to write for a module to make it compatible with the Views module. In the latter case, the question is marginally about the Views module, and it is more about the code the OP should write for her/his own module.

Comment: I am not saying that those tags must be kept at any cost. I am just saying that there is probably a reason to keep one of them. To me, it is useful, as when I see a question tagged [tag:tic-tac-toe], I avoid reading it. `:)`

Comment: Shouldn't the master tag be [tag:xs-and-os]?