# Let's stop [Chat]tering

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

At the moment, we have a tag called [chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat). This seems like a meta tag.

We use this tag for the following:

- Asking how a chat works on some platform: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219532/how-does-in-browser-chat-work)
- Off-topic questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081660/how-can-i-add-chat-facilities-to-my-drupal-6-site)

The above list is just a small selection of the bad questions on this tag.

Even the tag wiki says it can mean 2 things:

> Generic term for "Instant Messaging System". It can also represent a discussion that occurs in an Instant Messaging System.

I think we should clean this tag up and either make it have only one meaning, or totally burn the tag away.

There are 3354 Questions at the moment tagged as this.

Comment: If someone's instead using it for help in creating a chat system, then it'd be no worse than [flappy-bird-clone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273079/we-have-a-flappy-bird-clone-tag-really)

Comment: Maybe rename/re-tag most of them to [instant-messaging]? The first few pages of that search all should really be tagged with that one, not with \[chat\].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instant-messaging

Comment: I think we should just burn it. It's essentially just a more general synonym of many other tags.

Comment: Anyone care to add an assessment of burnination criteria?

Answer (score 5):

[chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat) keeps growing, as of March 2, 2023 it has 5,779 questions. The tag excerpt is still the same.

IHMO the potentially "worst" combinations:

- [[chat] [facebook]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat+facebook) 147 questions
- [[chat] [whatsapp]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat+whatsapp) 45 questions
- [[chat] [messenger]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat+messenger) 37 questions
- [[chat] [telegram]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat+telegram) 26 questions

... gmail, google-talk, google-hangouts, google-chat, google-workspace, skype, discord, slack, linkedin.

Also not "nice":

- [[chat][message]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat+message) 91 questions
- [[chat] [bot]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat+bots) 78 questions
- [[chat] [chatbot]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat+chatbot) 72 questions
- [[chat] [instant-messaging]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat+instant-messaging) 55 questions