# Clean up of "ChatGPT" questions

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

I just read a newsletter announcing the launch of ChatGPT API by OpenAI. This question is not about the ban about using generated text content in Stack Overflow. Also it's not about posts that use "ChatGPT" or "Chat GPT" as a common name, or trivial mentions like "asked ChatGPT", "ChatGPT told me" and alike, but about questions that are on-topic, good or bad (might be good if they are improved).

Since the launch of ChatGPT there have been several questions asking different things about "ChatGPT API". On several of them there are comments saying that there was no official ChatGPT API. I posted some of them, but that changed.

Nowadays [openai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai), [chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt), [chat-gpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat-gpt) are synonyms of [openai-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai-api), so most of these questions are tagged [openai-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai-api), but others not have this tag. Some might have [chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat), [chatbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatbot); in the best cases they include appropriate tags like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) among others.

A few days ago, someone kindly told me that [chatbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatbot) should be used only in questions about the implementation of *chatbots*, and should not be included in questions about ChatGPT (that are not directly about the implementation of a chatbot). I understand that the same applies to [chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat). Considering this, is it correct to say that:

- [chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat) and [chatbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatbot) should be removed if the question is not about implementing a chat/chatbot, e.g. questions about using ChatGPT in a web browser, embedding ChatGPT in a website, web scraping https://chat.openai.com/chat, creating a web browser extension to interact with https://chat.openai.com/chat
- [openai-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai-api) should be removed if the question is not about using one of the OpenAI API end-points.

---

Related

- [Disambiguate [chatgpt] and [openai]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422589/1595451)
- [Let's stop [Chat]tering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314235/1595451)

Comment: Ugh. The chatbot tag description is woefully ambiguous. There is nothing in there that would prohibit its usage for questions that are about an existing chatbot implementation. I'm sure that is how that unnamed person would like that the tag is used but right now there is not a lot of proof that this is shared by the many. The chat tag according to its description is specifically about instant messaging systems - what a terrible tag name.

Comment: This is a programming site. Why is it surprising that questions must be about implementing something using programming? Similarly, the [tag:fork] tag must be used for questions about programming using the Unix function with that name, not for questions about kitchen utensils. Every single tag on the site has this criteria, it is nothing unique to chat-bot-related tags.

Comment: And [tag:chatgpt-api] appeared. No tag wiki yet.

Comment: @Gimby: I think Rubén is referring to me, but mis-stated what I said; I said that [chatbot] isn't appropriate for questions about *the output of* existing chat bots.  This was on *[Does this ChatGPT "swap" snippet do anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75415943)*,  a question asking if (and how) the code ChatGPT generated made sense.  (The code was in fact buggy and didn't make complete sense.  The question asking about it was way too optimistic about ChatGPT understanding what it was doing enough to simulate an ARM CPU and test its code, but is otherwise not a terrible question.)

Comment: have no objection to [chatbot] being tagged on questions about writing code that uses (via an API or otherwise) existing chatbots, as well as about implementing new ones.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, yes I was referring to your feedback related to the rollback you made of my edit to replace [tag:openai-api] by [tag:chatbot] on the question linked in your comment.

Comment: @PeterCordes Don't tell me, tell it to the tag description :)