# What tags might help me find questions about "prompt engineering"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm trying to find SO on-topic questions about *prompt engineering*.

According to several articles on the Web from AI experts, *prompt engineering* is the fine art of *writing* an input to get from chatbot like DALL-E, ChatGPT and others a valuable output looks to be tagged with [prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prompt), [command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line). The Wikipedia article about this term make it look a lot more complex but maybe both are right, just explaining the term in different context and for different audiences.

Anyway, seeing *prompt engineering* as *writing prompts*, might look like a trivial task but a good *prompt engineer* besides wrinting the prompt also have to think about other API parameters like the maximum number of tokens to be returned by the API, the number of options to request the API to calculate, etc.

My first candidate was [prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prompt). This tag has 2,264 questions. Current tag excerpt (there is no tag wiki body)

> prompt is a command-line or graphical interface which presents the user with a line editor or modal dialog and suspends execution until input is returned

But this tag looks to be a meta-tag:

*prompt is a*

- command-line or
  *we already have [command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line)*
- graphical interface which presents the user with a line editor
  *we already have [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface)*
- modal dialog and suspends execution until input is returned
  *we already have [modal-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modal-dialog)*

[command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line) has 23,235 questions, but it doesn't look to be used yet for questions related to *prompt engineering*, or at least I'm not able to find additional terms that help me.

There aren't many questions using the term *`prompt engineering`* (two words, separated by one space). Specialist from the field looks to just use *prompt* or *input*. Any hint?

---

#### Progress

Looking at [command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line)+[nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp) questions

- [Natural language command language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1605493/1595451) from 2009
  It's about designing a language and *prompt engineering* is about *using* a language in an optimal way

---

#### Related

- [Clean up of "ChatGPT" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423455/1595451)

Related from Artificial Intelligence

- [Are "prompt engineering" and "prompt design" used as synonymous?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/39168/42632)

Comment: Exploring [tag:huggingface]: found [Chatbot Start Prompt for GPT-J](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73841325/1595451), [GPT-J (6b): how to properly formulate autocomplete prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75324242/1595451)

Comment: My initial inclination is that prompt engineering, as it exists today, is off-topic on Stack Overflow.  It seems like a form of writing/engineering that is not programming, as we understand the field of programming today.  But I'm not a subject matter expert on prompt engineering, so take that with a grain of salt.  Perhaps there's an argument that it is programming, or maybe it is so intertwined with programming that it can't reasonably be separated from the programming aspects of building systems based on these models.

Comment: Thanks @RyanM. I'm not a AI / prompt engineering SME either but I have strong feeling that some might be on topic as it's not, as I understood so far, to be something like making lists of / collecting "cooking recipes"

Comment: As it is now, "prompt engineering" isn't programming. As described, it's *entirely* about writing human language text which is intended to illicit a particular response, or a response with particular qualities, from an AI, primarily a chat-bot AI. That's not programming. That's *using* a program. While it might help someone to be effective at this to have knowledge of programming and AI, it's not actually programming.

Comment: Previous (deleted) meta discussion on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422793/do-we-need-a-new-tag-for-prompt-engineering-and-will-such-questions-be-allowed-o

Comment: Also see [What would be the appropriate community to ask questions about prompt engineering? (Like for GPT-3 or Stable Diffusion.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383127)

Comment: Re *"The Wikipedia article about this term ... just explaining the term in different context and for different audiences."*: No, I think the Wikipedia article is ***at odds*** with the current (new?) meaning ([sample](https://odysee.com/@eevblog:7/eevblog-1531-can-chatgpt-generate-all:f). Or at least in [this one](https://odysee.com/@eevblog:7/eevblab-106-chatgpt-ai-has-changed:1)), the old being about ***training*** and the new being about getting ***useful output*** from AI systems (two different things). It adds to the confusion.

Comment: Related: [Starting the Prompt Design Site: A New Home in our Stack Exchange Neighborhood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390463/241919)

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out in the comments, you shouldn't be able to find prompt engineering in any Stack Overflow tags because it is off-topic. The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) sets out what is on-topic, and prompt engineering hits none of them:

> - a specific programming problem, or

Well, prompt engineering has no code, so it's not really a programming question.

> - a software algorithm, or

You could make an argument here that prompt engineering falls under this, but it's a shaky one. At best, prompt engineering is about how to use someone else's model, not how that model works or its applications.

> - software tools commonly used by programmers;

Unless you're using AI to write code ([which isn't a good idea to begin with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)), this doesn't apply.

> - and is
>   a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Prompt engineering is likely to be subjective and opinion-based, so questions regarding prompt engineering aren't really answerable (objectively, at least). A lot of AI models are closed source too, so a complete answer is likely impossible and open to speculation.

---

It looks like you wrote [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385963) over on Meta Stack Exchange, almost answering your own question. However, I'd have to disagree with that answer. All the communities you list, except for Artificial Intelligence, are either about programming or data science. I'm not on the Artificial Intelligence community, but it looks like the most appropriate place for prompt engineering to me. You might want to ask whether or not its on-topic on the meta over there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I disagre with the premise of this answer "because it is off-topic", in first place because this is not a reason to not found something, in second place because *prompt engineering* is not completely off-topic. It's like saying that we should not be able to found nothing about *sotfware engineering* because it's off-topic. By the other hand the referred ban isn't reason to say that the use of AI to write code is a bad idea, that is an overgeneralization. Also disagree with the other arguments.

Answer (score -6):

Tl;Dr: Considering the comments from the moderators, as of March 2, 2023, *prompt engineering* understood in a oversimplified way as "writing prompts" looks to be off-topic and it's hard to imagine an on-topic question as, generally, it uses *human language* rather than a *programming language*.

By the other hand, *prompt engineering* understood as a broader concept as it's explained by Wikipedia, it might be too broad to have a specific SO tag for it considering that there are already other tags that include it as a concept or that includes parts of it.

---

I have reviewed many questions of several tags, searches combining tags and keywords. Most of the posts that include *prompt engineering*, *prompt design* and most of the posts that include prompts / inputs without using the terms *prompt engineering* / *prompt design*, are not questions enterily focused in *prompt engineering*. There are few having an answer telling the OP that what they are looking is *prompt engineering* with the repective explanation (not including links to avoid the *Meta Effect*).

---

From [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385963/289691) to [What would be the appropriate community to ask questions about prompt engineering? (Like for GPT-3 or Stable Diffusion.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383127/289691)

[artificial-intelligence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence), [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning), [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp), [reinforment-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reinforment-learning), [gpt-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpt-2), [gpt-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpt-3), [stable-diffusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stable-diffusion) , [openai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai) (this is a synonym of [openai-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai-api))

---

[openai-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai-api) questions about the APIs of code completions, text completions, chat completions (ChatGPT API), image generation (DALL-E API), fine tuning  OpenAI base models as the paylood of their respective http requests should include one or more *prompts* (writen instructions using human language), i.e., from https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/making-requests

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/completions \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" \
-d '{"model": "text-davinci-003", "prompt": "Say this is a test", "temperature": 0, "max_tokens": 7}'
```

---

Other related tags

- [fine-tune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fine-tune), [text2image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text2image) (no tag excerpt) (`[fine-tune] or [text2image]` have 115 questions )
- [huggingface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huggingface) it has only 272 questions
- [few-shot-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/few-shot-learning) it has only 11 questions

---

### Stack Exchange Network

AFAIK other SE sites, Artificial Intelligence SE, Data Science SE and Cross-Validated SE, Computer Sciences SE, Software Engineering SE, don't have a **specific** tag for *prompt engineering* yet.

#### Stack Exchange global search

- [[prompt]](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bprompt%5D) returns more that 9k  results

  - Included just to show that searching tags in the global search works to those who are unfamiliar with this feature.
- [[prompt-engineering]](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bprompt-engineering%5D) return 0 results
- ["prompt design"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22prompt%20design%22) returns 17 results
- ["prompt engineering"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22prompt%20engineering%22) returns 15 retults
  1 from [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com)
- ["prompt learning"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22prompt+learning%22) returns 6 results