# Should the [checker-board] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I just came across the [checker-board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checker-board) tag. Only 10 questions have been tagged with it, and no one follows it. It seems like a tag for a very... specific (for lack of a better word) problem.

Is there any value to this tag? Should it be removed?

Comment: Isn't a checker board... an array of arrays? 

Comment: @Maroun Perhaps in practice, yes. But it could also tag a question about making a game that involves checker boards.

Comment: I think the tag is useless..

Comment: I thought a checker board was what you played checkers on

Comment: I don't see any Q. on that tag where removing the tag would do any harm.  I agree with @Maroun, dump it.

Comment: It is a completely harmless tag.  Questions do not get better without it, reactivating 10 of them for no good reason is worse.  Just wait another couple of decades.

Comment: Wait no please I wanted a gold tag in the checker board tag!

Comment: @DavyM Though I understand you're joking, you would have to answer 200 questions about checker boards, and I can't even come up with 10 questions about them. (though perhaps that's due to giving up halfway through out of sheer boredom). Best of luck

Comment: Related question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273079/we-have-a-flappy-bird-clone-tag-really

Comment: Since this has just popped up in HOT META POSTS, checker board could also be in reference to [calibrating a camera with a black-and-white pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard_detection), which Wiki calls a chessboard, but that fortunately isn't a tag here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tag is useless, it doesn't meet any of the [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/204563) of when not to eliminate a tag.

I removed the tag from the 10 questions manually, it should be [gone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1tmkAFb_Os) shortly.