# Un[global]ise this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global) tag belongs to just over 4000 questions and has this summary:

> Refers to a space where variables and other items may be accessed from any scope.

The [globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/globals) tag belongs to just under 400 questions and has this summary:

> Refers to a spaces [*sic*] where variables and other items may be accessed from any scope.

So they mean the same thing, only the latter is pluralised, and has a typo.

Shouldn't these tags be synonyms?

Comment: Nuke them both.

Comment: I don't see any value in the [global] tag existing on a question. If the thing they're asking about is "global", they'd surely mention that in the question as well. Noone is going around filtering questions to topics about [global]

Comment: @KevinB check the accepted answer on [my other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415967/12860895). These tags are meta tags, so I think they should be kept.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/ Old, but i still generally agree with the points here. global isn't a tag that can stand on it's own and isn't useful for filtering. it therefore serves no purpose.

Comment: "Never use [globals]"?

Comment: so 4400 people thought that they need the tags, and already the tag was reviewed and nothing comes of it, so as always tags are needed to express what the people are searching, so they all should stay

Comment: Global anythings are usually so different between programming languages, and there's hardly a language-agnostic definition of "global" that these tags just aren't useful or informative, no matter the usage.

Comment: Also, **79** watchers for 4k questions!! And just look at the languages of the latest questions...C#, C++, Python, JS...

Comment: @nbk except that nobody search on stack overflow, they use google, and google sees everything.

Comment: There is afaik no requirement what-so-ever that each tag on the site must be able to stand on it's own.

Comment: @Lundin Are ya sure? ["Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @Braiam Yes I'm fairly sure, the part you quote about meta tags are examples that add no relevant _technical_ information at all, like [tag:beginner]. That's a meta tag. You could in theory post a stand-alone technical question about globals too, if this site had allowed broad, subjective program design questions. Similarly, I could post a question about the Python keyword `global` and only use the tag [tag:global]. That would have been just fine as tag use goes, but I wouldn't draw any attention at all to the post since the people who can answer it follow the [tag:python] tag.

Comment: @Lundin "stand-alone technical question about globals too, if this site had allowed broad, subjective program design questions" but the site doesn't, so that argument is DOA. "I could post a question about the Python keyword global and only use the tag global" And I would bet you a penny that you will not get an answer at all. Tags exists for the answerers, not for the askers or searcher or wtv.

Comment: @Braiam Still we have no rule against posting questions that will get very low traffic because they are missing tags and won't be found. The argument here is that the global tag _does_ stand alone. Seriously, if there exists something so very specific as a language feature or keyword and the spelling is a 100% match of a tag, how on earth did you come up with the conclusion that it's a "meta tag"? What is _not_ a meta tag then? [tag:C] is a "meta tag" because it's a letter as well as a programming language?

Comment: @Lundin I'm not talking about traffic, I'm talking about question quality. Also, we shouldn't false advertise that there are people answering questions about a topic that no one answers, it will end with the tag being eventually deleted by the mere fact that questions that has no answers are automatically deleted.

Comment: If y'all want to discuss a burnination, create a new question for it

Answer (score 13):

The tag [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global) should not be removed. Arguments follow below.
The tag [globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/globals) is just plural, it should be made a synonym of [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global).

---

[What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The tag isn't very meaningful on its own, but could be very meaningful when combined with a specific programming language tag. Something tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) + [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global) is for example completely unambiguous.

The term "global variable" is overall mostly unambiguous across all well-known programming languages. In some cases like Python, there even exists a formal keyword called `global`. In other cases it is informal slang but none the less a well-known term.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It is.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Possibly. Particularly when discussing scope, private encapsulation, program design etc. It definitely adds meaningful information is discussing a keyword `global`.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Pretty much, yes.

In some languages like C or C++ it is ambiguous if "global" means *declared at file scope* or if it means *external linkage*, but that's because global is no formal term in those languages.

> A tag must fail ALL of those tests in order to be considered for burnination.

It didn't, it didn't even fail one. It shouldn't be removed.

Comment: The [original post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/416654/1) didn't ask for anything to be removed, it was hijacked.

Comment: @user692942 Yes, the edit history looks strange. None the less, this answer applies no matter if it's a burnination request or a synonym request.

Comment: I agree with every word of this except I think it could be useful on its own in some edge cases.